# How to stop recycle of views in ListView

Tags: java, android

I am creating ImageViews dynamically in horizontal scroll. Means Images are scrolling horizontally in List view item. But my problem is if am scroll the List, Images are repeating dynamically. Please help me to stop this recycle of images.
If am scroll also it should display how much i added.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    System.out.println("getview:" + position + " " + convertView);
    View vi = convertView;`enter code here`
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textview1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        holder.textview2 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
        holder.imgscrollchild = (LinearLayout) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.imgscrollchild);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }   
    tempValues = (ListModel) data.get(position);
    holder.textview1.setText(tempValues.getName());
    holder.textview2.setText(tempValues.getDescription());
holder.imgscrollchild.addView(createimg(tempValues.getImage(),
            tempValues.getText()));`enter code here`
    return vi;
}
```

Comment: Post your adapter code

Comment: show your `Adapter` code

Comment: Pls check the above adapter code

Comment: Disabling view recycle in ListView would affect its performance. You should fix the repeating of images in your custom adapter.

Comment: I reverted the self-vandalizing edit. Without the code the question and answer are meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> holder.imgscrollchild.addView(createimg(tempValues.getImage(),
>             tempValues.getText()));
> ```

Here you're adding an image to a possibly recycled listview item, without removing any possible old views first.

Depending on your layout, adding

```
holder.imgscrollchild.removeAllViews();
```

before that line of code might be enough to solve the problem.

Comment: if i scroll first row horizontally. Why 5th row also getting scroll..?

Comment: Assuming you have a horizontalscrollview in a list item, call `scrollTo()` to reset it to a default position.

Comment: Where should i add that pls can u tell me clearly..? or pls can u edit the code..?

Comment: pls can u guide me..?

Comment: Access the scrollview with `findViewById()` and then call the method on it. If you need specific help, consider asking a specific question (and use the questions facility for that, not comments),